# How to make this code small by using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this piece of code which is very long.Can anyone suggest an idea as how to make it small .

I am trying to do it via for loop by taking the number of splits as length and calling the function but not sure how to pass each split .

```
def triggerexec(df_count,event_df):
    if  df_count <= 10000:
        print("Input partioned into 2 splits.")
        df_splits  = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0,1.0]))
        if df_splits[0].rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in 1st split")
        else:
            print ("Input count for 1st split: " + str(df_splits[0].count()))
            extract_and_push(df_splits[0])

        if df_splits[1].rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in 2nd split")
        else:
            print ("Input count for 2nd split: " + str(df_splits[1].count()))
            extract_and_push(df_splits[1])
    elif 10001 <= df_count <= 50000:
        print ("Input partioned into 4 splits.")
        df_splits = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
        if df_splits[0].rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in 1st split")
        else:
            print ("Processing 1st split")# + str(df_splits[0].count()))
            extract_and_push(df_splits[0])

        if df_splits[1].rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in 2nd split")
        else:
            print ("Processing 2nd split ")# + str(df_splits[1].count()))
            extract_and_push(df_splits[1])

        if df_splits[2].rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in 3rd split")
        else:
            print ("Processing 3rd split")# + str(df_splits[2].count()))
            extract_and_push(df_splits[2])

        if df_splits[3].rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in 4th split")
        else:
            print ("Processing 4th split")  # + str(df_splits[3].count()))
            extract_and_push(df_splits[3])
```

Comment: Should this question not be under http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It seems quite obvious that there is a repeated pattern in this code, which could easily be broken out into a separate function and a loop.

Comment: @PaulRooney Wow, very helpful (_irony_). OP asks, how to do it and your help is _it's obvious_...

Comment: @PaulRooney Pretty sure the reason why OP posted this, is that this is not obvious to them.

Comment: @quapka I did not say its obvious, don't paraphrase me . I said theres an obvious pattern and offered some high level options to tackle the issue. He already knows he needs to use a loop. I think its a helpful comment. Was not intended to be condescending.

Comment: Thanks Guys, will check it out.

Comment: @occasionalvisitor one question, isn't df_count accesible from event_df? I'm not sure what they really are, they look like pandas dataframes, but if you can access df_count from the event_df you should not pass it to the function as an argument, instead calculate it inside the function what will make your code less error prone.

Comment: Ya @Adirio, I am doing a count on a pyspark dataframe and then passsing it to function. will move the count inside the function

Comment: @occasionalvisitor Perfect then, which solution from the proposed you choose depends on you as the three are pretty much the same. Just make sure to end the `if ... elif ... else` tree with an else statement so that every case is considered, maybe using the else as a default option. I would opt for my second answer as this removes the most ammount of code from the `if ... elif ... else` tree just leaving there the real difference from the cases, the number of fragments but that's just a personal preference.

Comment: I prefer the second answer with the enumerate.

Comment: I would still suggest using an empty list for your default case if you just dont want to do anything. The for-each loop will loop for every item, since there is none, it would just skip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to take the repetetive tasks to another funcion and execute it. I made this function general for N splits so theres no need to call it inside the different `if`s.

```
def splits(df_splits):
    for i, split in enumerate(df_splits):
        if split.rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in split number " + str(i+1))
        else:
            print ("Input count for split number " + str(i+1) + ": " + str(split.count()))
            extract_and_push(split)

def triggerexec(df_count,event_df):
    if  df_count <= 10000:
        print("Input partioned into 2 splits.")
        df_splits  = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0,1.0]))
    elif df_count <= 50000:
        print ("Input partioned into 4 splits.")
        df_splits = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
    else:
        # Either do something in every case posible, return, or throw an error, but make sure that the splits(df_splits) is not called id df_splits is not defined
        return
    splits(df_splits)
```

A little more complex solution would accept another argument as a parameter and split it in the outter function:

```
def split_this(event_df, n):
    print("Imput partitioned into " + str(n) + " splits.")
    df_splits = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0]*n))
    for i, split in enumerate(df_splits):
        if split.rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No data in split number " + str(i+1))
        else:
            print ("Input count for split number " + str(i+1) + ": " + str(split.count()))
            extract_and_push(split)

def triggerexec(df_count,event_df):
    if  df_count <= 10000:
        splits = 2
    elif df_count <= 50000:
        splits = 4
    else:
        # Default case:
        splits = 10
    split_this(event_df, splits)
```

Credit to @Lex for the enumerate part and the default case.

Comment: Love users who downvote solutions without commenting, probably the previous answer was the one dovoting because his didn't work properly and deleted it

Comment: It will be balanced ;)

Comment: @iFlo Thank you, 2 rep lost is not the end of the world, but the reaction of that users is the one of a 5 year old kid, just surprises me that instead of trying to debug his solution following my comment on his answer so that I remove the downvote, he deletes and downvotes mine to get 1 reputation back for himself

Comment: split_this(event_df, splits) in the "little more complex solution" might be called with undefined splits, for df_count larger 50000

Comment: @Lex True, editing it. The simple solution also has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 Version:

```
def triggerexec(df_count,event_df):
    if  df_count <= 10000:
        print("Input partioned into 2 splits.")
        df_splits  = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0,1.0]))
    elif df_count <= 50000:
        print("Input partioned into 4 splits.")
        df_splits = event_df.randomSplit(([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]))
    else:
        df_splits = []

    for i, split in enumerate(df_splits):
        if split.rdd.isEmpty():
            print("No Data in split Nr. {:d}".format(i))
        else:
            print("Input count for split Nr. {:d}: {:s}".format(i, split.count()))
            extract_and_push(split)
```

This is all in one function using enumerate for the index, which is more charming way IMO

Comment: What's the problem with this in Python2? Haven't tried it but don't see any problem. BTW, `10001 <= ` part is not nedt and is actually slowing the code.

Comment: Im so much into Python3 that i don't know if Python2 does support all these features i use ^^. Thx for the check bigger 10000 part, edited the code